# how to access to a $scope value into a controller

Tags: angularjs

can someone explain me why i cannot get the `$scope.pk` value in my `console.log()`

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp')
  .controller('TweatCtrl', function ($scope, $location, djangoAuth, djangoTweat, $routeParams) {
    $scope.tweek = function(){
        console.log(' tweek ');
    };

    djangoAuth.profile().then(function(data){
        $scope.user = data;
        $scope.pk = data.pk;
    });

    djangoTweat.getUserTweeks(1)
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.tweeks = data
        },function(data){
            // error case
            $scope.errors = 'no tweeks';
        });
    console.log($scope);
    console.log($scope.pk);
```

The fisrt `console.log()` returns me the Scope object with a pk value.
The second `console.log()` returns 'undefined' :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access `$scope.$pk` before it is set.

The following code is probably run asynchronously, as it is using promises. It will run some time after the `console.log` statements at the end of your controller initialization. It will only run if the `djangoAuth.profile()` promise is resolved (succeeds).

```
djangoAuth.profile().then(function(data){
    $scope.user = data;
    $scope.$pk = data.pk;
    // now log $scope.$pk after it is set (assuming data.pk is not undefined)
    console.log("$scope.$pk is", $scope.$pk, "and data.pk is", data.pk);

});
```

Comment: it's a correct assumption. it's done via promise that way it is correct.
it should be wrapped in $timeout or _.deffer

Comment: Using $timeout with promises and asynchronous functions is not good practice. While it may work, depending on the delay you set, it's not guaranteed to activate after your promise returns. Regarding `_.defer()`, that would mean you are wrapping a promise in a promise, which is a little redundant.

Comment: @IamStalker, what are you referring to with "it"? Please be more specific.

Comment: thanks. Then i have to learn about "defer" so understand how to do it.

Comment: @billyJoe I would suggest looking into understanding promises first

Comment: yep, i'm on, hard to understand for a noob but i'll got it :)

Answer (score -1):

i saw a declaration of $pk, your're trying to log a pk attr of $scope..

Console.log($scope.$pk); //it should be ok..

Another thing, i suggest you to use $log, and include it in the function of the controller, then, you'll be able to use $log.Error, $log.Debug and $log.log to the standard console..

Comment: Excuse me, it's a missprint while i test :( nope, it's not.

Comment: $pk it's a custom provider, it's doesn't seems to be correct.

Comment: A custom provider should be declared before using. and its not. the only "*pk*" thing that was "set" is a attr of $scope, and its $scope.$pk. and even if it would be declared its logged before inited.

Comment: @LiorBenAharon yes. actually it' being call before it's initiated as stated after you.

I think you should re-check your answer.